# Configuring Fed-lab.org as Identity Provider

Tags: configuration, saml-2.0

MY AIM : I am creating a Service provider at my local server using opensaml-java latest library from shibboleth.I want a Test IdP.I chose https://fed-lab.org/ . There is no clear procedure for this configuration also

1.I have created Metadata programmatically using opensaml. 
I need to check whether my metadata is correct according to its standard schema.How can i check this?

2.I have registered my SP at https://fed-lab.org/ site after logging in.

3.I have downloaded the Identity Provider from https://fed-lab.org/online/identity-provider-metadata/

It has two IDPSSODescriptors. 
In that SIngleSignOnServices are 
1.https://openidp.feide.no/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php and 
2.https://fed-lab.org/simplesaml-test/module.php/fedlab/SingleSignOnService.php

I am using HTTP-Redirect binding

I have created the AuthnRequest message first . then did , deflate , base64encoding , URL encoding as per [specification of SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0#HTTP_Redirect_Binding)

https://openidp.feide.no/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php?SAMLRequest=processedAuthnRequest

I am trying to access this URL , But I am getting nothing Response from the site.

WHere am I wrong ? please Let me help to figure it out.

Can u provide Test IdPs where there is a clear way(documentation) to do the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple Idp at http://stubidp.kentor.se that doesn't require any kind of registration. Just enter your acs url and a subject nameid to send an unsolited Saml2Response.

It won't let you test everything (yet), but it can get you started on receiving a basic message and handling that.